# Instance is already running (windows task)

Tags: taskmanager, task-management

I have a task, `task` which (for now) is really just an R-script which writes "2" in an excel-file and saves that file (it is a test script).

Now, I want to run that on a remote desktop every day, say 12:00. I can set up the task, and if I right-click and press "run" it works as intended. If I just let the time pass untill 12:00 it says "another task is already running". When I right-click and click "run" it takes less than a second thus I cannot understand, why it cannot be executed on a specific time, since it is not due to that the task not having enough time before it is called again.

I can force it to work by not checking "don't run if another instance is running", but I still wonder, why it does not run by itself